# Управление adbd

Tags: java, android

Приветствую уважаемые программисты и форумчане. Возник следующий вопрос . Все мы знаем про adb , fastboot и так далее. Но как мы знаем , все они связываются с adbd(Android Debug Bridge Deamon) , который и принимает команды. Но как я могу управлять им без adb? И есть ли такая возможность вообще? Например могу ли я прямо из своего мобильного приложения им управлять или например с терминала Linux?